# Service for data analysis of big data like in Excel

Tags: data-analysis

Is there any web service to analyze big data sets and plotting graphics like in Excel? I need something simple, efficient and with web GUI.

Comment: Without the web GUI requirement I would suggest QlikView. A very powerfull in memory tool. There is a Personal Editon for free. But only the server version is able to publish to a web GUI. But may be it is interesting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Fusion Table](https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories?ft_source=tour_nav&__utma=1.1686898028.1302240969.1302240969.1302240969.1&__utmb=173272373.2.10.1302240922&__utmc=173272373&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1302240969.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=220198169) might be a candidate for your choice.

[Google Docs](https://docs.google.com) also can be your choice, if you just want simple Excel-like graphics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more controll over the analysis (not just using Excel as a table editor), you can try analytic tools like BellaDati (https://service.belladati.com/login). It is still free for personal use.

Google Fusion Table is good for data mining but not analysis and createing charts. Bi software creates good summary charts/pivot tables etc. not scientific charts. What kind of data you want to analyse?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

[Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is this kind of tool you could give it a try. It can connect to CSV files or OLAP Cubes and do any pivot operations just like excel. It is web based and totally run inside browsers.

And it is pure javascript implementation which can be easily embedded into any web application as a component.

Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).